# Re-use speechT example with LSTM network

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

From example at https://github.com/timediv/speechT, I'm trying to adapt to use with LSTM network but failed please help. I tried many combination but I always got error i.e. Input must be sequence or else. I need to implement LSTM network to the example to for speech recognition purpose and after I tried for couple of weeks I still get stuck in the coding problem. Anyone can help me provide example of using LSTM network with the sample will be good.

```
class InputBatchLoader(BaseInputLoader):
    def __init__(self, input_size, batch_size, data_generator_creator, max_steps=None):

    super().__init__(input_size)
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.data_generator_creator = data_generator_creator
    self.steps_left = max_steps

    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):


with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
      # Define input and label placeholders
      self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None, input_size], name='inputs')

      self.sequence_lengths = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size], name='sequence_lengths')
      self.labels = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32, name='labels')

      # Queue for inputs and labels
      self.queue = tf.FIFOQueue(dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.string],
                            capacity=100)

      # queues do not support sparse tensors yet, we need to serialize...
      serialized_labels = tf.serialize_many_sparse(self.labels)

      self.enqueue_op = self.queue.enqueue([self.inputs,
                                        self.sequence_lengths,
                                        serialized_labels])

class Wav2LetterLSTMModel(SpeechModel): #Add Sep 14, 2017 to create LSTM model

  def __init__(self, input_loader: BaseInputLoader, input_size: int, num_classes: int):
super().__init__(input_loader, input_size, num_classes)

  def _create_network(self, num_classes):

cellsize = 256
num_layers = 3

inputs = self.inputs
lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(cellsize, forget_bias=1.0)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

return tf.transpose(outputs, (1, 0, 2))

def create_default_model(flags, input_size: int, speech_input: BaseInputLoader) -> SpeechModel:
  model = Wav2LetterLSTMModel(input_loader=speech_input,
                      input_size=input_size,
                      num_classes=speecht.vocabulary.SIZE + 1) #Add Sep 14, 2017, to use LSTM model

  # TODO how can we restore only selected variables so we do not need to always create the full network?
  if flags.command == 'train':
    model.add_training_ops(learning_rate=flags.learning_rate,

learning_rate_decay_factor=flags.learning_rate_decay_factor,
                       max_gradient_norm=flags.max_gradient_norm,
                       momentum=flags.momentum)
model.add_decoding_ops()
 elif flags.command == 'export':
model.add_training_ops()
model.add_decoding_ops()
  else:
model.add_training_ops()
model.add_decoding_ops(language_model=flags.language_model,
                       lm_weight=flags.lm_weight,
                       word_count_weight=flags.word_count_weight,
                       valid_word_count_weight=flags.valid_word_count_weight)

  model.finalize(log_dir=flags.log_dir,
             run_name=flags.run_name,
             run_type=flags.run_type)

  return model
```

Comment: Actually how do we feed  self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None, input_size], name='inputs') into outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

Answer (score 0):

At last I use this

```
XT = tf.transpose(inputs, [1, 0, 2])
XR = tf.reshape(XT, [-1, self.input_size])
X_split = tf.split(XR, cellsize, 0)

lstm = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(cellsize, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, _states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm, X_split, dtype=tf.float32)
```